# How to publish a KMM library for android project to consume it?

Tags: android, maven, kotlin-multiplatform, sonatype

I have made a KMM library, I want to publish it in localMaven so that native android app can consume it. I am following this [article](https://dev.to/kotlin/how-to-build-and-publish-a-kotlin-multiplatform-library-going-public-4a8k), But the issue is after running the command `./gradlew publishAllPublicationsToSonatypeRepository`, even though its shows Build Successful but it’s still not creating the staging repository in **Sonatype**

. Is there anything that I am doing wrong here
This is my local.properties

```
signing.keyId=last 8 digit of my id 
signing.password=passphrase used 
ossrhUsername=my userName
ossrhPassword=password
signing.secretKeyRingFile=secret-key.gpg
```

I exactly have same code that is given in the article for `convention-plugin` just with a small change,  in its build.gradle file I just have added

```
 kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }
```

as without it, I was getting this error

```
xecution failed for task ':convention-plugins:compileKotlin'.
> Error while evaluating property 'compilerOptions.jvmTarget' of task ':convention-plugins:compileKotlin'.
   > Failed to calculate the value of property 'jvmTarget'.
      > Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 20
```